# manipulate products array in actionPresentOrder hook in Prestashop 1.7.8.x

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm attempting to manipulate thr products array in the actionPresentOrder hook as follows:

```
public function hookActionPresentOrder($params)
{
    foreach ($params['presentedOrder']['products'] as &$product) {
        $product['image'] = 'test;
    }
}
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Order\OrderLazyArray has no effect
```

Any suggestions on how to modify the products array would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following method worked for me:
$params['presentedOrder']->offsetSet('products', $products, true);

Not sure if this is the correct approach, please correct me if it is not

Answer (score 0):

That's just because `$params` must be a reference, not a value. Try this:

```php
function hookActionPresentOrder(& $params) {

}
```

(Note the `&`).